# Move object array along curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a simple mesh that forms a belt around a *BezierCircle* with the help of an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier. I want to move the belt forward and animate it.

[image: The belt]

The common way to do this is to simply move the object, but when I do this, I get:

[image: Not positioned correctly]

I also already tried *Follow Path* constraint and duplication frames; neither worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found it out myself: The curve was not looping.

- Move the object so that the error is clearly visible.
- Select curve, go into edit mode.
- Find the segment where the array modifier quits the curve.
- There, look for the ending of the curve (The segment is not attached to its beginning) and select it.
- Tool shelf, "Toggle Cyclic".

[image: Toggle Cyclic button]